# Link inacessivel no IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, deploy

Estou fazendo uma aplicação em C# usando o padrao MVC. A mesma utiliza um banco de dados do FireBase do Google.

Executando esta aplicação pelo depurador do Visual Studio, funciona normalmente, porém ao tentar publica-lo em *localhost*, através do gerenciador do IIS, a aplicação dá erro de conexão com o *host* do servidor, e ambas as execuções são no mesmo computador e mesma rede e ja verifiquei algumas configurações de firewall no computador e no iis, mas nao da resultado.

Dá esta mensagem do print abaixo:[image: Imagem execução do aplicativo]

```
public ActionResult GetMenuPrincipal()
{
    FirebaseDB firebaseDB = new FirebaseDB("https://link-firebase/");
    FirebaseDB firebaseDB1 = firebaseDB.Node("Projects");
    List<ProjectModel> projectModels = 
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ProjectModel>>(firebaseDB1.Get().JSONContent);

    return PartialView(projectModels);
}`
```

Comment: Vamos la, primeiro o erro diz que um servidor de ip x.x.x.x:443 demorou para responder, então ,  aonde está o codigo que acessa a esse ip ? 
Dois troque o @{ Html... } por @Html...

Comment: Se estiver rodando em algum cloud (Google Cloud, AWS), verifica se o firewall está permitindo acesso ao IP de onde você está executando.

Comment: @Marcos Brinner, segue o codigo, estou usando metodos que tratam o firebase como api rest, mesma implementação do link [link(https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-c-sharp-wrapper-over-firebase-api-for-basic-crud/)
'public ActionResult GetMenuPrincipal()
  {
   FirebaseDB firebaseDB = new FirebaseDB("https://link-firebase/");
   FirebaseDB firebaseDB1 = firebaseDB.Node("Projects");
   List<ProjectModel> projectModels = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ProjectModel>>(firebaseDB1.Get().JSONContent);
   
   return PartialView(projectModels);
  }'

Comment: @resposta1 Eu verifiquei o firewall do windows para programas, nao verifiquei regras de ip, porem acredito que nao tenha restrição, ja que pelo visual studio executa sem problemas.

Comment: @LeandroBuenodeSouza pode colocar seu codigo na pergunta, nos comentarios não da para ve-lo

Comment: @MarcosBrinner, inseri na pergunta, o restante da implementação esta conforme o link do penúltimo comentario

Comment: Bom aparentemente seu  codigo está ok, todas as respostas aqui que poderei lhe dar serão meio superficas mas  podem  ajudar de algum modo. verifique se o servidor do firebase não está bloquando o ip do seu pc, outra coisa, as  configuações no visual studio são diferentes para o IIS geralmente pode ser algum  problema de permissão no  usuário do seu IIS

Comment: de uma verifica em  IIS -> Application pools -> select pool -> Advance Settings.

Comment: e aqui  você pode ver uma explicação de como  funcional o  IIS sobre  serviço local  e o Visaul Studio

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32279751/connection-string-works-from-visual-studio-but-does-not-work-from-iis

Comment: @MarcosBrinner desculpa demorar a responder, estive meio ocupado esses últimos dias, não encontrei onde encontra nas configurações avançadas o local que da permissão no próprio usuário dentro do iis, mas olhei e a pasta da aplicação e seus arquivos esta com permissão no usuário que executa a aplicação, inclusive permissão de escrita.